# Compressing Memory Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, compression

Does anyone have any experience in using compression on their cached data?
I understand that stackoverflow is internally using this method.

What are the pros and cons?

And are there any gotchyas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman just created a Session wrapper class that can zip items before putting them into your cache/session/whatever. You may want to take a look!

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode35ZipCompressingASPNETSessionAndCacheState.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, great to compare implementations

Comment: Hanselman notes that you can get data expansion from the built-in DeflateStream (or GZipStream, whatever he used).  As I have posted elsewhere, this is a known anomaly. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=93930   You need a different stream to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

you should try memcached. It's a distributed caching server that is easy to use and provides impressive compression capabilities.

Comment: Is memcached worth while if only using a single server?